# Sub query ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

When executing the query below I get the following error message

***Error message:***

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

The error message points to the following sub query

***The error is caused in***

```
SELECT t4.TIN FROM table4 t4, table5 TRA WHERE .... ORDER BY t4.TIN ASC
```

I'm not good with queries at this time and was hoping if someone can point to me what I'm doing wrong.

***Query***

```
SELECT 
    t1.TIN AS "Employee TIN", 
    t2.NAME AS "Employer Name", 
    MAX(t3.SUMMARY_NUM) AS "Summary Number"
FROM 
    table1 t1, 
    table2 t2, 
    table3 t3
WHERE 
    t1.SUMMARY_YEAR = 2017
    AND t2.TIN = t1.TIN
    AND t3.SUMMARY_NUM = t1.SUMMARY_NUM 
    AND t3.TIN IN(SELECT t4.TIN FROM table4 t4, table5 TRA WHERE .... ORDER BY t4.TIN ASC)
GROUP BY t2.NAME, t1.TIN
ORDER BY t1.TIN ASC
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `order by` in the sub-select is completely useless

Comment: Hmm, replacing part of the part that is suspected to be erroneous with "`....`" isn't really the best choice. And so are old school implicit `,` joins. Maybe you want to switch to explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - it is not unrelated, that is exactly what is causing the error.

Comment: @mathguy yes that's true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `ORDER BY` from

```
(SELECT t4.TIN FROM table4 t4, table5 TRA WHERE .... ORDER BY t4.TIN ASC)
```

Illustration:

```
SQL> select count(*) from emp
  2  where deptno in (select deptno from dept order by dname);
where deptno in (select deptno from dept order by dname)
                                         *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis


SQL> select count(*) from emp
  2  where deptno in (select deptno from dept);

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

SQL>
```

Comment: You just save me from throwing the server to the garbage thanks, oracle always so precise, so specific with their error messages.

Comment: Think green, @Neto Yo :) I'm glad if it helped.